# How to redirect from a normal JavaScript page to angular 6(microsite to angular 6)?

Tags: javascript, performance, redirect, optimization, overhead-minimization

I just want my landing screen to be built in normal JavaScript to reduce the load and redirect to my angular 6 app on click of any buttons in landing screen.

How can I redirect from `index.html` to another (Angular) `index.html`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple buttons on your page, you can trigger a redirect for all the buttons like this:

```js
var buttons= document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = "https://google.de";
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the `window.location.replace()` method or updating the value of the `window.location.href` property.

The calling the `window.location.replace()` method simulates a HTTP redirect and updating the value of the `window.location.href` property simulates a user clicking on a link.

You would use them as:

```
// similar behaviour as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("index.html");
```

Or:

```
// similar behaviour as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "index.html";
```

You could also create a hidden link and trigger a click on it, like this:

```
<a href="index.html" style="display: none"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
</script>
```

If you wanted the link to open in a new tab, you'd use the `target="_blank"` attribute, like this:

```
<a href="index.html" style="display: none" target="_blank"></a>
```

Good luck.

Comment: But how can we redirect to the build file of angular from outside.

Comment: What do you mean, can't you just use a regular link like `<a href="/x/y/z.html">Example Link</a>`?

Comment: Ya got it. But can i pass any parameter in the url to check which button clicked in the angular part

Comment: I don't really see why you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: In the angular side our routing will be   { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: AppComponent }, where as we want to distinguish the button value from the other index html. Lets say i passed  -> window.location.replace("a/index.html/frompage/buttonVlaue") from my landing page, the routing is not getting corrected even if i change the route to { path: 'fromPage/:pageValue', pathMatch: 'full', component: AppComponent },

Comment: I think you would be better off creating a new question with your specific code problem where you can get dedicated help for that solution.